# Meta-analysis of correlated proportions

Tags: meta-analysis

```
  stage1 n1 stage2 n2
1      4 10      7 10
2      3 20      5 20
3      2 30      3 30
4      1 40      4 40
```

I have information on 4 studies (one per row), and I have information on how many people have the disease at each stage. Study #1 has 10 individuals, and 4 people have the disease at stage1 of the trial (proportion = 0.4). At stage2, we now have 7 people that have the disease  (proportion = 0.7).

I want to perform a meta-analysis of these proportions at each stage (stage1, stage2) across the 4 studies. However, I don't think I can assume that the proportions at stage1 is independent of that at stage2 because they depend on the same group of individuals. And these proportions are monotonically decreasing (once you have the disease you can't revert). What method is appropriate here? I know that fixed and random effects models are commonly used for meta-analysis but those are usually for combining the effect size at a single time point. How can I extend this to this scenario?

Comment: I've dealt with this, but it was for a meta-analysis of regression coefficients. I ended up doing a three-level meta-analysis using the `metafor` package for R. You can see if one of the examples here http://metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses fits what you are looking for.

Comment: What is your objectives? Compare the proportions at stage 1 and 2? Estimate the proportions at stage 1 and 2?

Comment: My objective is to combine the proportions at stage1 across all studies. And combine the proportions at stage2 across all studies. I think the stages are correlated, so instead of doing 2 separate meta-analyses. I would like to perform 1 meta-analysis that accounts for the correlation between the proportions at the 2 stages.

Comment: Why not treat it as a three-valued outcome and use an oredered logistic regression?

Comment: what is Stage I and Stage II

Comment: what objective do you want to realize ?